# Jenkins : Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException while trying to trigger child job

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-cli, eofexception

I am trying to execute following command :

```
java -jar /jenkins-cli.jar -s http://example.com:8080/jenkins build childJob
```

However, I get following error :

> java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:244)     at
>   hudson.cli.Connection.readBoolean(Connection.java:93)     at
>   hudson.cli.CLI.authenticate(CLI.java:573)     at
>   hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:484)    at
>   hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:390)

I tried to access it remotely as well as from same machine.
Any leads would be appreciated.
**UPDATE :**  This only happens for first hit (on each try), upon hitting same command again, it works.

Answer (score -1):

The Web says that this will happen, if you are trying to execute that command with an user that is not registered to Jenkins, also called **unknown user** :)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But to help me on this question, can you elaborate your answer- What exactly registration here means? Which link you came across?